# Creating a thread for a database in Qt: a reasonnable design or nonsense?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

the application I'm trying to design with Qt is quite data intensive; it is essentially a database. I'm looking for a design that would allow me to keep the UI reactive. My guess is I should keep only the UI in the main thread and create a thread for the database.
However:
- creating a database object inheriting from QThread doesn't seem to be a natural design (what would run() be? )
- I assume I would need to use signals and slots for UI / core interaction; yet this feature seem to be relatively recent in Qt, so I'm wondering if my "design" is wrong.
- QObject descendants are apparently designed to live in the thread in which they were created, so I'm concerned the communication of models (from the database thread) to the UI thread will be problematic.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The QT 4 is very signal/slot centric. First paragraph.  
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Indeed; so I understand that you're suggesting that although the cross thread support got included only recently in Qt4, this is (as the Qt4 name suggests) a big evolution and thus it's ok that this new technique becomes very central.

Comment: Using signals and slots in QT is a vary standard practice. Using multi thread software is a necessity today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using [QtConcurrent::run()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrentrun.html#run).  You'll pass in the function you want.  It'll spool off a thread to run the function and give you a [QFuture](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuture.html) that you can use to get the eventual result.  You could poll the QFuture to see if it `isFinished()`.  Better, however, may be to use [QFutureWatcher](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuturewatcher.html) which watches the QFuture for you and emits a signal when it's done.  See the example code blurb in QFutureWatcher.

Comment: QtConcurrent includes functional programming style APIs for parallel list processing, including a MapReduce and FilterReduce implementation for shared-memory (non-distributed) systems, and **classes for managing asynchronous computations in GUI applications**

Comment: The best part is that QtConcurrent will use an many threads as reasonable for the system. On a common quadcore, it may very well use 4 threads. That's better than deriving the database from QThread, and having only two threads (UI included) in your entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think creating a separate thread for the DB stuff is a good idea... but I would suggest that you only make 1 thread for the DB stuff (not 2, 4, or more). The reason is that unless you are an expert at DB concurrency issues and the locking mechanisms of your DB, things will get complicated.

The thing is that you should not have any other threads mixed with code that has gui or in main of a gui project because any blocking will freeze the GUI as well. So as long as you make a separate DB handler class and thread that, I think you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Once I asked that same question "Is this design good?" (after detail explanation), the answer I got is "when doing a design of something, only the sky is the limit".

If you think threads might cause problems, then you should start processes, instead of threads.

Don't forget that you can always block and disable widgets when doing some intensive computation (a famous hourglass icon).

Signals and slots are implementation of observer pattern. In my opinion, it is one of the very useful design patterns. It allows you to easily break dependencies. If you don't like signal slots, then take a look into [events](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/eventsandfilters.html).

**EDIT**

For processes, you can use IPC (inter process communication) - not necessarily using stdout. There are pipes, shared memory and messages.

As for freezing the widgets, you can disable them, or the mouse (turning it into a hourglass) when your application is doing some computation intensive operation, and when you think the GUI might become unresponsive. Or, you can show the invisible widget covering your GUI and change the mouse into the hourglass. This way the mouse events would go to the invisible widget and ignored. You can also add "please wait" box on top of it.

You didn't say what exactly you are trying to achieve. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
I don't see how QProcess could be used as an alternative : UI requesting a model to set up a view through stdout seems complicated...  
As for freezing the widgets, either that's what I'm trying to avoid, or you're referring to an use I do not understand. (if you have the time, any clarifications would be appreciated)

Comment: Events seem to be an interesting lead, but I don't really see how they differ from a signal / slot communication: when the slot is in another thread, it will be executed in the event loop of the receiver [signals-and-slots-across-threads](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute VJo. I didn't know about IPC, and indeed this seems to be very interesting. What I am trying to achieve is having a GUI that doesn't freeze on a database. GUI is used to display views of some parts of the data, and editing them. Some operations of the database can take too long to execute, I would like the user to be able to do some other things / cancel those operations when needed. The communication between thread is about the models underlying the view. Database should also be able to send "I'm done" events to GUI so that the result is displayed.

Comment: @Sam In that case, you have to use either a thread or a process. To make the GUI responsive, you can raise the priority of the GUI thread.